# MySQLi object issue

Tags: php, mysql, object, mysqli

I am trying to create a query to MySQL DB.

```
$result = self::$link->query($query) or trigger_error("This cause database error: ".self::$link-error."["$query"]");
```

The problem is, that I cant access the variable $ressult as object.

```
if (($result->num_rows > 0){
  $records = array[];
  while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)){
  $records[] = $row;
}
  $result = $records
}
```

Where am I wrong?

Thank you for your time and answers.

Comment: For the record: Missing semi-colon at the end of `$result = $records`

Comment: is `result` maybe a boolean? also does this even compile?

Answer (score 1):

The last line should be:

```
$result = $records;
```

You missed a ; (semicolon)

Answer (score 1):

I think your **$result** equals NULL

check if it not null

```
if($result != null) {

    if (($result->num_rows > 0){
      $records = array[];
      while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)){
      $records[] = $row;
    }
      $result = $records
    }

}
```

---

**Enjoy :)**